# CountVectorizer Token Pattern

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I need the scikit-learn CountVectorizer to identify as one token words containing the symbol '-'.  This is because I deal with tags like 'cooking-time' that shall not be splitted in two.

I guess the point is setting the right regex in the token_pattern parameter but I can't manage to do that.

I am trying something like

```
token_pattern=u'(?u)\b\w\w+(-)?\w+\b'
```

Comment: any positive and negative example after this regex was applied?

Answer (score -1):

It's easier to just write your own tokenizer, for example:

```
def Tokenize(text):
    for char in (',', ';', ':'):  # Here the special chars you want to remove
        text.replace(char, '')
    return text.split(' ')
```

Then pass directly the callable (the function without trailing parentheses) to CountVectorizer.